# Can I find the mean of values who share the same last two digits of an ID number and create a new column with those means?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-processing

I am new to using R for data analysis and am struggling to find a way to feasibly process my data.

I have left an example data table below. I would like to be able to average points with the same last two digits, as they are the same distance from the stream. I was able to make three different data files to separate the data by cross section, but now need to find a way to average rows from columns in separate data files, and then would like to make a data file such as the one pasted below the code.

```
streams<- read.csv("Soil Temp Gradient - DATA.csv")

s1z1 <- streams[streams$Point.ID %in% 11000:11320, ] #extracts data from stream 1 zone 1 and makes new data frame 

s1z1cs1<-s1z1[s1z1$Point.ID <=11120, ] #creates data frame with stream 1 zone 1 cross section 1 data 

s1z1cs2<-s1z1[s1z1$Point.ID >=11201 & s1z1$Point.ID <11301, ] #creates data frame with stream 1 zone 1 cross section 2 data 

s1z1cs3<-s1z1[s1z1$Point.ID >=11301 & s1z1$Point.ID <=11320, ] #creates data frame with stream 1 zone 1 cross section 3 data
```

I've tried separating my data by using the group_by(), matches(), starts_with() and ends_with() functions but haven't been able to make them work for what I', trying to achieve. Some code I had tried to use is pasted below.

```
#Sample data frame I'm working with:
Zone  Cross.Section  Point.ID  Point.Temp
1            1           1101        3
1            1           1102        7
1            1           1103        2
1            2           1201        4
1            2           1202        6
1            2           1203        3
1            3           1301        3
1            3           1302        8
1            3           1303        5

#What I'd like to see in a final data frame:
Zone Point.ID  Avg.Pt.Temp
1      01         3.333
1      02           7
1      03         3.333
                       
stream1%>% select(Point.ID, matches("^113.*2$"))
  
  select(starts_with("113"))

  select(Point.ID, c(starts_with("11")),ends_with("01")))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you,
Faye K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `base::substr()`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Zone, Point.ID = substr(Point.ID,3,4)) %>% 
  summarize(Avg.Pt.Temp = mean(Point.Temp))
```

Output:

```
   Zone Point.ID Avg.Pt.Temp
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>
1     1 01              3.33
2     1 02              7   
3     1 03              3.33
```

Input:

```
df = structure(list(Zone = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Cross.Section = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Point.ID = c(1101L, 
    1102L, 1103L, 1201L, 1202L, 1203L, 1301L, 1302L, 1303L), 
    Point.Temp = c(3L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```